# Twig_Error_Runtime exception with "url" function

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

after updating twig to > than 1.7

code `<a href="{{ url('article', { 'articleId':article.id }) }}">` causes:

`Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Twig_Environment::addFunction() must implement interface Twig_FunctionInterface, instance of Twig_Filter_Function given`

with 1.7 - everything is ok

Comment: my guessing - issue related to symfony version, currently symfony is locked to some of 2.1-dev hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `path(...)` instead of `url(...)`.
Arguments are the same.

I suppose that from 1.7 to > 1.7 this function became obsolete and was substituted with new one

Answer (score 1):

the problem not with `url` or `path` functions.
it looks like you are using `Twig_Filter_Function` instead of `Twig_Function_Function` for defining your custom functions.
check your custom twig extensions.